# children not staying inside parent divs

Tags: html, css, grid-system

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uatzust3/

Here is the fiddle for my problem, you'll observe that the children are not staying inside the parent div `card` and also I want the `div`s to take full width of parent which they are not taking.

Also, where should I be learning best practices? I am new to the community. Thanks in advance.

The left div`(black_container)` is short of content but should arrange the height according to the width of the right div`(content_container)` all the while staying inside the `card` div.

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30), 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.black_container {
  height: inherit;
  background: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 3%;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.content_container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3%;
  /* position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0; */
}
.small_bar {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: 30px auto 5px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.designation {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.qrcode_container {
  float: right;
}
.qr_container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.qr_text {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.qr_text>li {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}
.bars {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.bars .small_bar {
  width: 15px;
  background: #777;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
}
.qr_code {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  padding: 5px;
}
.button {
  width: 150px;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="black_container">
    <div class="circular">
    </div>
    <p class="small_bar"></p>
    <p class="name">wow</p>
    <p class="name designation">Front-End Designer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content_container">
    <!-- qr code container ends -->
    <div class="qr_container">
      <div class="qrcode_container">
        <ul class="qr_text">
          <li>LOREM</li>
          <li>IPSUM</li>
          <li>DPOLER</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="bars">
          <div class="small_bar bar"></div>
          <div class="small_bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qr_code"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- qr code container ends -->
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>Hello!</p>
      <p>My name is lorem</p>
      <p>I am a web designer</p>
      <p>Im stuck</span>
      </p>
      <div class="button">button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want three div are in single row?

Comment: add your css...

Comment: It is hard to determine the design that you are trying to accomplish by looking at the code alone. I would suggest few read about [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [CSS3 Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), [multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts), or [Bootstrap grid to get things up to speed](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Comment: Thank you LJ . I will But I cannot use bootstrap because as a designer it would be very easy to use bootstrap and get done with the problem. but to actually accomplish the design without bootstrap will be my real test.

Comment: @dreamhunter Css is in the fiddle link provided....thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A parent cannot take the height of a direct child if the child is `absolute` because the `absolute` elements are removed from the document flow(like `floats`), so in this case "card" doesn't even know "content_container" even exists .

https://jsfiddle.net/OmarIsComing/eq4L86g9/1/

update:

solution with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/OmarIsComing/eq4L86g9/2/

solution without flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/OmarIsComing/eq4L86g9/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help.Your solution doesn't let the 'black_container' div take the full height and the 'content_container' take the full width. If you can help me with that it would be great.

Comment: thanks....it worked....can you give me a clear idea of how and why we're using position absolute and position realtive for the divs inside card. thanks....

Answer (score 0):

If `flexbox` is an option, this is easy :

1. Add `display: flex` to your `card`
2. Add `flex: 1` to the `content-container`

See demo below:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 25px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30), 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.black_container {
  height: inherit;
  background: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 3%;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
.content_container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3%;
  /* position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0; */
  flex: 1;
}
.small_bar {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: 30px auto 5px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.designation {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.qrcode_container {
  float: right;
}
.qr_container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.qr_text {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.qr_text>li {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
}
.bars {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.bars .small_bar {
  width: 15px;
  background: #777;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
}
.qr_code {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  padding: 5px;
}
.button {
  width: 150px;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="black_container">
    <div class="circular">
    </div>
    <p class="small_bar"></p>
    <p class="name">wow</p>
    <p class="name designation">Front-End Designer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content_container">
    <!-- qr code container ends -->
    <div class="qr_container">
      <div class="qrcode_container">
        <ul class="qr_text">
          <li>LOREM</li>
          <li>IPSUM</li>
          <li>DPOLER</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="bars">
          <div class="small_bar bar"></div>
          <div class="small_bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qr_code"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- qr code container ends -->
    <div class="card_content">
      <p>Hello!</p>
      <p>My name is lorem</p>
      <p>I am a web designer</p>
      <p>Im stuck</span>
      </p>
      <div class="button">button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class card-body, this will keep the contents inside of the card.

```
<div class="card border-success">
    <div class="card-header border-success">
        <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>      
    </div>
    <div class="card-body border-success">
        <dl>
            <dt>
                Stuff
            </dt>

            <dd>
                Stuff Details
            </dd>           
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

replace the `.content_container` css with:

```
.content_container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I think the CSS attribute `position: absolute;` is causing this issue. In short, `absolute` position removes the element from the flow of other elements; therefore, its height is simply ignored, and never counted in your `.card` container.